# Из-за чего Exception?

Tags: c, ncurses

Есть следующий код написанный на C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

char *buttns[] = {"New game", "Settings", "Exit"};
int counter = 0;

void update(){

erase();

    for(int d = 0; d < 3; d++){
        if(d == counter){
            attron(A_BOLD);
            attron(COLOR_PAIR(1));
            printw("$s\n", buttns[d]);
            attroff(A_BOLD);
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(1));
        }else{
            attron(COLOR_PAIR(2));
            printw("%s\n", buttns[d]);
            attroff(COLOR_PAIR(2));
        }
    }

}

int main(){
    initscr();
    start_color();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    noecho();

    init_pair(1, COLOR_RED, COLOR_BLACK);
    init_pair(2, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);

    int ch = 0;

    while(ch != 'q'){
        update();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Однако при запуске команды gcc Source.c, выдает такой Exception, и как я понял трассировку:

/tmp/ccKQq01a.o: In function `update':
Source.c:(.text+0xb): undefined reference to`stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0x13): undefined reference to `werase'
Source.c:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to`stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
Source.c:(.text+0x4e): undefined reference to`stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `wattr_on'
Source.c:(.text+0x7f): undefined reference to`printw'
Source.c:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to `stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to`wattr_off'
Source.c:(.text+0x9f): undefined reference to `stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0xb1): undefined reference to`wattr_off'
Source.c:(.text+0xba): undefined reference to `stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to`wattr_on'
Source.c:(.text+0xeb): undefined reference to `printw'
Source.c:(.text+0xf2): undefined reference to`stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0x104): undefined reference to `wattr_off'
/tmp/ccKQq01a.o: In function`main':
Source.c:(.text+0x122): undefined reference to `initscr'
Source.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to`start_color'
Source.c:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `stdscr'
Source.c:(.text+0x13b): undefined reference to`keypad'
Source.c:(.text+0x140): undefined reference to `noecho'
Source.c:(.text+0x154): undefined reference to`init_pair'
Source.c:(.text+0x168): undefined reference to `init_pair'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Как исправить?

Comment: Это означает, что ваш проект не видит библиотеку, в которой эти функции определены.

Comment: Компилируйте с указанием нужных библиотек. В данном случае -- `gcc t.c -lncurses`

Comment: @avp Спасибо, скомпилировалось, однако теперь не выводит "Меню".

Comment: Curses реально выводит символы на экран не сразу, а после вызова, например, `refresh()` (в каком-то ответе тут я уже это описывал). Вставьте в конец своего `update() { ...` вызов `refresh();`. Только у вас все равно программа бесконечно циклится, она же не читает (не меняет) переменную `ch`. И вообще, погуглите ссылку на curses tutorial и почитайте...

Comment: @avp Большое вам спасибо! Хочу сделать выпускную работу для ПВТ, вот и начал графику консольную учить, ну и последний вопрос, может быть знаете какую-нибудь либу для работы с окнами на C, типа javax.swing в java?

Comment: Зависит от ОС. Сам только через Tcl/Tk окошки из С-программ в \*nix делал (с запуском Tcl/Tk в отдельном процессе и интефейсом через псевдотерминал)

Comment: @avp Прошу прощение за тупизм, но Tcl/Tc - хедер для c? А пишу под *nix

Comment: Tcl/Tk это отдельный продукт. Tcl -- скриптовый язык на идее, что все есть определенным образом отформатированная строка. Tk -- набор оконных виджетов  для Tcl. Программа на Си может работать с Tcl/Tk получая от него строки и посылая туда строки, имитируя неким образом человека за терминалом.

Comment: @avp А почему, кстати, не видит ncurses.h? Я запускал sudo apt-get install ncurses-dev. И как итог, в папке /usr/include, появились хедеры

Comment: Кто не видит? Компилятор, естественно, видит ncurses.h (иначе все свалилось бы с диагностикой про `#include`). А линкер по умолчанию знает только про libc (ну, почти...) А про то, что библиотеку `libncurses` (из /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/) в которой код всех функций curses, надо подключать не знает. Вот ее мы и указываем ключем `-l ncurses`

Comment: Кстати, использовать лучше ncurses**w**, не в 20 же веке живём!

Comment: **какую-нибудь либу для работы с окнами на C** если именно на С, то самая распространённая - "GTK+ (сокращение от GIMP ToolKit) — кроссплатформенная библиотека элементов интерфейса (фреймворк), имеет простой в использовании API".  Введение можете посмотреть здесь: https://habrahabr.ru/post/135809/